# Widening Var-args vs. Boxing Var-args

Tags: java, variadic-functions, boxing

Hi may i know what's the problem, the compiler is giving me
The method gos(int[]) is ambiguous for the type Main

here's the code

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Main().gos(1);
    }

    public void gos(int...ls){
        System.out.println("long...");
    }
    public void gos(Integer...integers){
        System.out.println("Integer...");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two methods with same name and same parameters.

Integer is (almost) same as int, so when you call "gos", compiler is not able to decide, which one you want to call.

You probably only mispelled, change your "long" method to this will do the trick :

```
public void gos(Long... ls) {
        System.out.println("long...");
    }
```